# (php) how to use preg_replace function to replace all chars except numbers and css units?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, preg-match

I need a `preg_replace()` expression that removes all characters (letters & punctuations) except numbers and css units. But i need it to match the exact units not letters in it.

For example I wrote this expression:

```
$check = preg_replace( '/[^(0-9|px|em|\%|pt|cm|auto)$]/', '', '80sd0sdfdfpx');
echo $check;
```

And the result is:

```
800px
```

Thats ok untill this example:

```
$check = preg_replace( '/[^(0-9|px|em|\%|pt|cm|auto)$]/', '', '5sdfasdfp');
echo $check;
```

And this returns:

```
5ap
```

As you can see it also returns the letters which css unit variables contains. Like `a in auto` and `p in px`.

So I need it to return the css units if the words exactly matches like in the first example.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match and skip sequences you have and remove anything else using SKIP-FAIL regex:

```
$check = preg_replace( '/(?:[0-9%]|p[xt]|[ec]m|auto)(*SKIP)(*F)|./', '', '5sdfasdfp');
echo $check;
```

See [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/h3QqrN)